# how to print out when a new record is set (within an array) using random numbers

Tags: python, arrays, random, graph, matplotlib

I've generated a graph of random numbers (standard deviation 1, mean 0). I need to run through the list and print out each number if it is the biggest one currently seen. For example, given the list `[10, 5, 15, 18, 5, 7, 9, 100]`, the code would print out:

```
10 (first number is always going to be the biggest currently seen)
15
18
100
```

Here's my code:

```
import pylab
a = pylab.arange(1.0, 129.05, 1)
xrandn = pylab.zeros(129, float)

for j in range(0, 129):
    xrandn[j] = pylab.randn()

pylab.plot(a, xrandn, "r-")
pylab.xlabel("Year")
pylab.ylabel("Units")
pylab.title("Possible Tempertaure Fluctuations")
pylab.show()
```

Also, as an extra, how could I mark these points on the graph itself?

Edit 1:
thanks for your replies, im now stuck on the following

I now need to generate a large number of random number "sets" from which I need to be able to retrieve the maximum value of the first value in every set and there after be able to access the second value of every set, then the third in every set etc counting the numbers of values that exceed the previous maximum. I have tried creating a matrix to do this for me, however I keep getting the error message telling me I cant use floating numbers within a matrix, and I am now unsure if this is the correct method or if some sort of amendment to the previous code will yield the answer .

```
import pylab

def make_list(size):
    """create a list of size number of zeros"""
    mylist = []
    for i in range(size):
        y = pylab.randn()
        mylist.append(y)
    return mylist

def make_matrix(rows, cols):
    """
    create a 2D matrix as a list of rows number of lists
    where the lists are cols in size
    resulting matrix contains zeros
    """
    matrix = []
    for i in range(rows):
        matrix.append(make_list(cols))
    return matrix

mx = make_matrix(10, 6)

print(mx)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple as it can be

```
def foo(data):
    lastMax=[data[0]]
    for x in data[1:]:
        if x>lastMax[-1]:
            lastMax.append(x)
    return lastMax
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach may be to plot a separate stairstep curve for the running maximum:

```
>>> def running_maximum(data):
        result = data[:1]
        for x in data[1:]:
            result.append(max(x, result[-1]))
        return result

>>> data = [10, 5, 15, 18, 5, 7, 9, 100]
>>> running_maximum(data)
[10, 10, 15, 18, 18, 18, 18, 100]
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will print out all of your record highs, and return their values, and the index they occurred at in an array.

```
def print_current_max(data):
    m = data[0]
    print m # First point will always be the biggest one yet seen.
    highs = [(0, m)]
    for (i, x) in enumerate(data):
        if m < x:
            m = x
            print m
            highs.append((i, m))

    return highs
```

You can then plot all the high points as follows:

```
highs = print_current_max(data)
X = [x for (x, y) in highs]
Y = [y for (x, y) in highs]
pylab.plot(X, Y, 'o')
```

Comment: could you offer some more advice regarding my next program (edit is within same question), thanks